# Using Terraform to manage multiple AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Could someone please give me an example of how to programmatically create Terraform provider aliases based on a variable map?  This is what I've tried, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
variable "aws_regions" {
  default = [
    {
      region = "us-east-1"
      alias  = "default"
    },
    {
      region = "us-east-2"
      alias  = "useast2"
    },
    {
      region = "us-west-1"
      alias  = "uswest1"
    },
    {
      region = "us-west-2"
      alias  = "uswest2"
    },
    {
      region = "eu-central-1"
      alias  = "eucent1"
    }
  ]
}

provider "aws" {
  count  = "${length(var.aws_regions)}"
  region = "${lookup(var.aws_regions[count.index], "region")}"
  alias  = "${lookup(var.aws_regions[count.index], "alias")}"
}

# CloudWatch Log Groups
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "linux" {
  count    = "${length(var.aws_regions)}"
  provider = "aws.${lookup(var.aws_regions[count.index], "alias")}"

  name = "Linux"
}
```

Error:

```
$ terraform plan
* provider.aws.${lookup(var.aws_regions[count.index], "alias")}: count.index: count.index is only valid within resources
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that Terraform provider processing takes place very early and the current version (v.0.11.3) doesn't currently support variable interpolation for providers.  I did discover a workaround that isn't too terrible, but it requires a lot of code duplication.

**main.tf**

```
# Default Region
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  version = "~> 1.8"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-1"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-east-2"
  region = "us-east-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-1"
  region = "us-west-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "us-west-2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "eu-central-1"
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

# CloudTrail Setup in Default Region
module "cloudtrail" {
  source = "./cloudtrail"
}

# CloudWatch Setup per Region
module "us-east-1_cloudwatch" {
  source = "./cloudwatch"
  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-east-1"
  }
}

module "us-east-2_cloudwatch" {
  source = "./cloudwatch"
  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-east-2"
  }
}

module "us-west-1_cloudwatch" {
  source = "./cloudwatch"
  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-west-1"
  }
}

module "us-west-2_cloudwatch" {
  source = "./cloudwatch"
  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.us-west-2"
  }
}

module "eu-central-1_cloudwatch" {
  source = "./cloudwatch"
  providers = {
    "aws.region" = "aws.eu-central-1"
  }
}
```

**cloudwatch/main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "region"
}

# CloudWatch Log Groups
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "linux" {
  name     = "Linux"
  provider = "aws.region"

  tags {
    OS = "Linux"
  }
}
```

Comment: `provider.tf` _does_ support interpolation. `terraform.tf` is the file that doesnt.

Answer (score -1):

Use workspaces - it can be used for replicable use cases such as dev environments and multi-regions.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Comment: This answer I believe might be unrelated to the question.  There is a capability to use a workspace to manage a distinct region, but in this example/request, they want to iterate through multiple regions for a single feature which is regional (eg: cloudtrail / guardduty).  Workspaces for a different use-case might be a valid answer, for this use-case I think it isn't.  I previously downvoted this, but I removed the downvote in favor of simply a large comment for others to read.

Comment: The reason I think it's not an answer, is I am assuming the author isn't actually managing 16 AWS regions.  If they were, workspaces _might_ be one valid approach.  Since I believe they likely aren't (99% of the customers I've worked with over the last 10 years have been single-region) then creating 16 workspaces and making them terraform apply 16 times is not ideal.  I wouldn't wish that on anyone.