# How to create SNS topics in multiple regions with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, terraform, amazon-sns

Aim : Use terraform to create an SNS topic in multiple regions.

Right now it lets me create a single SNS in the default region or one specific region i input.

Hurdles :

- providers.tf doesnt support iterating the region via a list
- sns topic creation in terraform doesnt take allow region arguments to be passed as well.

The only workaround i could do is do something found here -

[Using Terraform to manage multiple AWS regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632797/using-terraform-to-manage-multiple-aws-regions)

But this involves a lot of code duplication and is not efficient or scalable.

Is there any efficient iterative approach to solve this problem ?

Comment: Seems that's the accept answer and the only answer. So what's wrong for the exist solution, typing the duplicate codes? If you are good golang developers, you are welcome to raise PR to hashicorp terraform directly for this feature to support multiple region with terraform.